# Error in xy.coords dealing with NAs

Tags: r, plot, na, variable-length

I'm getting the following error when I run the plot code: `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`. I have many `NA`s in my data set which I understand is causing the problem. Any ideas as to:

1. how to deal with NAs in R, and
2. how to make sure I can plot plots of variables with differing lengths?

I looked at some similar questions posted here, but unfortunately couldn't make sense of it. Needless to say, I'm new to R.

```
 df <- read.dta("r12.dta")
 attach(df)
 model1 <- lm(rent~I(income^2)+income*races)
 fitted(model1)
 layout(matrix(1:4,2,2))
 plot(model1)
 plot(income, fitted(model1), xlab="Income", ylab="Rent",
      main="Fitted Values for Black  Rent",type="l")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lm` object contains the variables (with `NA`s removed) as a dataframe in an element called `model`. So you can extract the relevant `income` variable from there to use in your plot:

```
plot(model1$model$income, fitted(model1), xlab="Income", ylab="Rent",
  main="Fitted Values for Black  Rent", type="l")
```

Comment: Thanks for editing and responding to my post. Great suggestion, thanks again!